# Is "equivalent" the same as "equal" (or "absolute equal")?

Tags: java, logic, discrete-mathematics

These two terms always stuck in my mind. Are they logically the same or completely different? For example, In Java book: *Introduction to programming by Liang*, he says:

> You can use a generic class without specifying a concrete type like
> this:
>
> `GenericStack stack = new GenericStack(); // raw type`
>
> This is **roughly equivalent** to
>
> `GenericStack<Object> stack = new GenericStack<Object>();`

Answer (score 1):

There are many levels of equality. Usually they are designated by words like "equal" or "equivalent". What these words mean exactly depends on the context, but usually equality implies equivalence, but not the other way around.

For example, given two pieces of code *A* and *B*, we could say that *A* and *B* are equal if they consist of exactly the same characters, and say that they are equivalent if we can always replace *A* by *B*, and vice versa, without changing the behavior of the program. If we do that,

```
int i;
i = 10;
```

and

```
int i = 10;
```

are not equal but equivalent.

The two code snippets in your quote are called "roughly equivalent" by the author. The word "roughly" suggests that they are not equivalent at all. And indeed:

```
GenericStack stack = new GenericStack();
GenericStack<String> stack2 = stack;
```

compiles (with a warning), whereas

```
GenericStack<Object> stack = new GenericStack<Object>();
GenericStack<String> stack2 = stack;
```

does not.

What the author means with "roughly equivalent" is that the raw type does behave like a `GenericStack<Object>` in many, but not all, cases. In particular, you can put any object in it.